# Return specific object value as a string in a function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to return an specific value as a string, but I end up getting the value in an array. Instead of getting **'unknown'**, I get **['u', 'n', 'k', 'n', 'o', 'w', 'n']**

> Challenge: *Create a function findWaldo that accepts an object and returns the value associated with the key 'Waldo'. If the key 'Waldo' is not found, the function should return 'Where's Waldo?'*

My code:

```js
function findWaldo(obj) {

  let values = Object.keys(obj);

  if (values.includes('Waldo')) {
    return Object.values(obj.Waldo);
  } else {
    return 'Where\'s Waldo?';
  }
};


// Uncomment these to check your work!
const DC = {
  'Bruce': 'Wayne',
  'Harley': 'Quinn'
}
const supernatural = {
  'Sam': 'Winchester',
  'Dean': 'Winchester',
  'Waldo': 'unknown'
}

console.log(findWaldo(DC)) // should log: 'Where's Waldo?'
console.log(findWaldo(supernatural)) // should log: 'unknown'
```

Comment: just return `obj.Waldo`.

Comment: Have you read the documentation to learn what [`Object.values`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and [`Object.keys`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) do? You’re probably looking for [`Object.hasOwn`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) for the test, and [property accessors](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: Just don't call `Object.values()`?!

Comment: …and you shouldn't use `Object.keys(obj).includes('Waldo')` either. Just check directly whether `'Waldo' in obj`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In your code `return Object.values(obj.Waldo);`, `obj.Waldo` has some string as its value.
- And  `Object.values()` method returns **array of a given object's**.
- That's why it's returning ```['U','n','k','n','o',w'], instead of "Unknown" as a direct string.
- If you just return `obj.Waldo`, than you will receive your desire output.
- Now just to modify your code, I will show you my approach.
- You can access `Object`'s property in two, one with `.`[dot] notation and another with `Object["Key"]`.
  -`Object["Key"]` will return  `undefind` if no value found for given string key value, so this will help you to create your logic.

```js
function findWaldo(obj) {
  if (obj['Waldo']) { // check if we have value
    return obj['Waldo'];
  } else {
    return 'Where\'s Waldo?';
  }
};


const DC = {
  'Bruce': 'Wayne',
  'Harley': 'Quinn'
}
const supernatural = {
  'Sam': 'Winchester',
  'Dean': 'Winchester',
  'Waldo': 'unknown'
}

console.log(findWaldo(DC))
console.log(findWaldo(supernatural))
```

Answer (score 0):

The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable string-keyed property values.

hence the output of unknown in array.

`Object.values(object)` returns values of object in array while `Object.values(string)` returns string split in a array

```js
function findWaldo(obj) {

  let values = Object.keys(obj);

  if (values.includes('Waldo')) {
    return obj.Waldo;
  } else {
    return 'Where\'s Waldo?';
  }
};


// Uncomment these to check your work!
const DC = {
  'Bruce': 'Wayne',
  'Harley': 'Quinn'
}
const supernatural = {
  'Sam': 'Winchester',
  'Dean': 'Winchester',
  'Waldo': 'unknown'
}

console.log(findWaldo(DC)) // should log: 'Where's Waldo?'
console.log(findWaldo(supernatural)) // should log: 'unknown'
```

Comment: This is just changing to `return obj.Waldo;` as the [comment to the question said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74955299/return-specific-object-value-as-a-string-in-a-function/74955360#comment132272600_74955299), right?